# How to reach PropertyDefinitions properties

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-plugin

In the JavaDoc, it's clearly defined how to set a property in SonarQube using `org.sonar.api.config.PropertyDefinition` in a plugin, however there is nothing on how to get it.

It seems to not work like `System.getProperty(key)` in Java, so, should I declare a new class that implements `Configuration`? Is there a way to reach these properties back properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a `Configuration` object through a `Context` one or by injecting it through extension point constructor:

`public MyExtensionPoint(Configuration config) {
    this.config = config;
}`

Use `context.config()` to get your Configuration object.

Then use `configuration.get("key")` to get the property.

Comment: Which `Context` are you talking about ? On `Plugin.Context` there is no `config()` function

Comment: Wow, that's what I was looking for, thank you @bergaco !!